# concatenate layer error due to needing matching shapes but they all match already

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Here's the error. Do you see any shapes that don't match?

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [[(None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1)], [(None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1), (None, 1, 1)]]
```

Is TF trying to say something else really?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, TF was trying to say the shapes were fine but there were two lists and it needs exactly one list. (Documentation and error messages could be better.) I figured it out via experimentation. The shapes were not the problem.

Code that fixed it:

```
  all_outputs_in_1_list = []
  all_outputs_in_1_list.extend(bias_outputs)
  all_outputs_in_1_list.extend(mm_outputs)
  x = concatenate(all_outputs_in_1_list)
```